# mysql using BTREE

Tags: mysql

How to solve this problem?
My table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_foster_network` (
  `network_id` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Network ID',
  `network_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Network Name',
  `network_domain` varchar(45) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Network Domain',
  `created_when` datetime NOT NULL COMMENT 'Created When',
  `last_modified_by` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Last Modified By',
  `last_modified_when` datetime NOT NULL COMMENT 'Last Modified When',
  PRIMARY KEY (`network_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `network_domain` (`network_id`,`network_name`,`network_domain`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='Network';
```

Error

```
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='Network'' at line 16
```

Answer (score 1):

The index type (`USING BTREE`) must come before the column list:

```
UNIQUE KEY uq_network_domain USING BTREE (network_id,network_name,network_domain)
```

From the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html):

```
[CONSTRAINT [symbol]] UNIQUE [INDEX|KEY]
      [index_name] [index_type] (index_col_name,...)
      [index_option] ...

index_type:
    USING {BTREE | HASH}
```

Comment: Okay you mean no need for "using BTREE"

Comment: USING BTREE is the default, so yes it is optional.